# SQL command to keep top 5 high scores only

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL database with e.g. the following table,

```
world    level    player_id     score
-----------------------------------------
1        1        1             100
1        1        2             123
1        1        3             130
1        1        4             200
1        1        5             90

1        2        8             234
.
.
.
```

For each unique `(world, level, player_id)` triple I want to record the top five scores only, as new scores come in.

My thoughts are to do the following: First insert the new score record, e.g.

```
REPLACE INTO Highscores (world, level, player_id, score) VALUES (1, 1, 6, 500)
```

Then keep only those records of the same `(world, level)` with the top 5 scores, e.g.

```
DELETE FROM Highscores WHERE world=1 AND level=1 AND score < (SELECT min(score) FROM (SELECT score FROM Highscores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5) AS Highscores);
```

But I was wondering if there was some other way to do this, perhaps with a single line of SQL, which might be more efficient?

**On tied scores:**

I assume that the last record in the table was added last, so in the case of ties, I want to keep the last record and remove the earlier record.

```
world    level    player_id     score
-----------------------------------------
1        1        1             100
1        1        2             200
1        1        3             100
1        1        4             100
1        1        5             100

1        1        8             200
```

Here, e.g. the row with `player_id=8` would be kept, but the row with `player_id=2` would be removed. `player_id=1, 3, 4, 5` would be kept too.

**Update**

In the end, by introducing an AUTO_INCREMENT unique `tableid` as primary key, I settled for the following approach:

```
REPLACE INTO Highscores (world, level, player_id, score) VALUES (1, 1, 6, 500)

DELETE FROM Highscores
WHERE world=1 AND level=1 AND tableid NOT IN
(SELECT tableid FROM (SELECT tableid FROM Highscores WHERE world=1 AND level=1
       AND score >=
       (SELECT min(score) FROM
           (SELECT score FROM Highscores WHERE world=1 AND level=1 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5)
           AS d)) AS c)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `ORDER BY score DESC` is non deterministic (random) in cases where the score ties as score is most likely a non unique column, meaning the result most likely will not be what you expected when ties are happening..

Comment: @RaymondNijland you are right. I will have to think about that one.

Comment: What happens if the fifth, sixth, and seventh are a tie? Do you want to show them all (7), or do you always want to show a maximum of 5?

Comment: @TheImpaler I've updated the question to hopefully explain.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite what you are looking for, but it should work. If you create the database with 5 'dummy' values, such as a negative player_id and a 0 score, this query will select the lowest, and replace it with the new score:

```
UPDATE Highscores
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT player_id
FROM Highscores
ORDER BY score ASC, player_id ASC LIMIT 1) rpid
ON Highscores.player_id = rpid.player_id
SET Highscores.player_id = 6, Highscores.score = 300
```

Just replace the last line with the values that you need. Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a62edc2d833e616f1bbd3f4cad01b757).

Note that this solution is based on the assumption that player_id is always set to increment, and only used once.

Comment: I'll look into using `UPDATE`. Two things I notice about this approach is that we would have to pre-populate the database with 5 entries for each level. Also, a higher high score can be overwritten by a lower high score, which kind of defeats the idea of a high score table. But with a few tweaks, this could work ! Thanks. PS Fiddle is so convenient.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked that. If you haven't modified it yet, adding WHERE `<= [new score]` to the inner query should make it work correctly [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d6bd51823a6265f1742ef6bc4e2729a)